# Can't access to magento connect manager

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-connect, ce-1.9.2.4, magento-connect-manager

I am trying to open the Magento connect manager from the admin and getting `403 -Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /downloader/ on this server.`

I changed the folders permission to 777 and make it read and write and nothing help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just add index.php after the /downloader/.

http://xxxx.com//downloader/index.php

Answer (score 1):

You can also check `.htaccess` file present inside your `downloader` directory. The `magento_root/downloader/.htaccess` file contains the following part of code:

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from xx.xx.xx.xx
```

You just have to replace the above `xx.xx.xx.xx` with your IP address. You can get your IP address by simply googling "what is my ip address".

Answer (score 0):

[It's not safe to use Magento connect for installing extension , click this link for more information.](https://www.integer-net.com/why-modules-shouldnt-be-installed-via-magento-connect-manager/)

in the worst case, if you want immediate solution , Alternatively you can install the extension through FTP (like FileZilla). You can paste the extension key [in this unofficial link](http://freegento.com/ddl-magento-extension.php) and you can download the extension files. Let me know if you find any problems in this.

**Note** : As this is unofficial 3rd party site, there is no guarantee about security. but i tested many extensions, i did't faced any security problems....

Comment: i don't know how it can help? any why hope for other soltution..